# How to Create OpenGL 3 Context with Qt 4?

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, qt4

I would like to learn graphics programming with OpenGL. And since I will just start learning it I decided to learn the new/OpenGL3 way of doing things.As far as I can see one has to create an OpenGL 3 context for this (Core profile in the new OpenGL 3.2 if I understand this correctly). Well I thought about using Qt for this, currently using version 4.5.2, since I know it already and like it and it supports creating the OpenGL widget. What I have the problem with is that it looks like the OpenGL widget is always crated with the old OpenGL 2 context and I can't see the option to make it in/switch it to OpenGL 3 way. Am I missing some obvious thing here or do I need something a bit more tricky to create OpenGL 3 context with Qt? Is it even supported in current version of Qt? I'm using Linux, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mesa software rendering is still stuck on OpenGL 2.1.  If you're using the binary NVidia drivers they provide OpenGL 3.2 [support](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/opengl_3_driver.html) on sufficiently recent hardware.  AMD's [latest fglrx](http://blogs.amd.com/play/2009/08/17/ati-catalyst%E2%84%A2-98-driver-everything-you-want-to-know-and-why-you-should-care/) supports 3.1.  Open Source drivers seem to top out around 1.3-1.4.

If you've gotten this far you'll probably have to hack the Qt sources to use GLX_ARB_create_context instead of GLXCreateContext to get a OpenGL 3.2 Core context.

[This guy](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=262519) seems to have had partial success, if you haven't already come across the thread via Google.