# how to create openGL 4.2 context with Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl, openglcontext

I'm looking for a way to create a OpenGL 4.2 context with Qt.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370577/how-to-create-opengl-3-context-with-qt-4) and [this](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=262519).

but those threads are more than 2 years old.. maybe there's a better way to do this by now?

//edit: oh, and if possible i'd like to have a portable solution to do this (but in the first place i'm interested in getting this to run on windows)

Answer (score 2):

Qt4 starting with 4.7 version can create context with requested version.
See here:

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglformat.html#setVersion
- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglformat.html#setProfile